# What is the Taskmaster's sword made up of?

Tags: marvel, the-taskmaster, ultimate-spider-man

In the TV series *Ultimate Spider-Man* season 3 also known as *Ultimate Spider-Man: Web Warriors* when Taskmaster fights Spider-Man he has a glowing sword. Is it a normal sword or is it made of energy or light (like a lightsaber)? What is this sword made up of?

[image: Taskmaster with his sword out: a glowing yellowy orange blade emits from the hilt]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "*photogenic energy sword*", according to the PS4 game *Marvel's Spider-Man*.

[image]

Comment: Of course, in reality photogenic just means "*producing or emitting light"*, so the explanation actually tells us nothing that we don't already know.

Comment: Taskmaster Vol 1 #2 (2002) had him playing with a SHIELD energy generator thingy; https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO98f.jpg. Not sure if they're related though.

Comment: I was just about to answer with the SHIELD energy generator. The colour is the same and they appear to act mostly the same, I think we can presume it is at least the inspiration for the sword.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I can think of at least one more inspiration for a glowing energy sword.

Comment: The in universe basis for it was probably better wording.

Comment: The crappy plastic toy just says *"energy sword"*; https://www.ebay.com/itm/CAPTAIN-AMERICA-CIVIL-WAR-MARVEL-LEGENDS-6-MERCENARIES-OF-MAYHEM-TASKMASTER-BAF/281926755648

Comment: @Valorum: Yeah, I enjoyed Asimov's Lucky Starr books too. :-D

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I was, of course, talking about that masterpiece of science fantasy, [Starcrash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiF6RLHqizc)

Answer (score -1):

If I had to guess, taskmaster had a shield which was made of pure energy and his sword looks very similar to it, so I’d probs says his sword is almost pure energy. He used one of these https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Energy_Shield and as mentioned, it has been depicted to look very similar to the sword here https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO98f.jpg

It’s fitting as the shield could “copy” or mimic things like caps shield, so it would also be fitting that his sword could do the same.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you add a source for the shield (spoiler, it's mentioned in the comments on the other answer) to flesh this out a bit more and add a bit more supporting evidence for it?

Comment: I didn't include the shield because it's from a different continuity. Also, the sword erupts from a pommel whereas the energy shield comes from a wrist-mounted device. Similar but not the same.